# lamplighter group - Growth from Fibonacci tree

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1 = \mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$ be the lamplighter group.

I'm looking at a proof that it's growth rate is $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ using a Fibonacci tree, as explained in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2244987_Random_Walks_on_the_Lamplighter_Group)

The **First Step** is to prove that $gr(G_1) \geq \varphi$. This is ok for me. Let $x=(m,\eta) \in G_1$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ the the position of lampligher, and $\eta\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ the states of the "lamps". Let $\text{flag}_R$ be the "first lit lamps" from the right, i.e.
$$ \text{flag}_R = \sup\{ k \geq 0, \eta(k)=1\}$$

You build a subgraph of the Cayley graph of $G_1$, as follow. The vertices consist of states $x=(m,\eta)$ for which $m\geq\text{flag}_R$ and $\eta(k)=0$ for all $k<0$. You start with the root $\Theta$ being the initial state ($m=0$, $\eta=0^\mathbb{Z}$) and for each vertex :

- if $m=\text{flag}_R$, then the vertex $(m,\eta)$ has one single child : $(m+1,\eta)$,
- if $m>\text{flag}_R$, then the vertex $(m,\eta)$ has two children : $(m+1,\eta)$ and $(m,\eta\oplus 1_m)$

Looking at the variable $d = m-\text{flag}_R$, building the tree it's easy to see that this form a Fibonacci tree : Each vertex has one single grandchildren with $d=0$, and each vertex has one single child with $d\neq 0$, hence the $n^\text{th}$ level has $l_n$ vertices with
$$ l_n = l_{n-1}+l_{n-2}$$
(we also need to prove that we never encounter twice the same vertex, this is ok because we never "walkback" from position, we can only go from $m$ to $m+1$)

Since the number of vertices at distance $n$ from the root of the Fibonacci tree is asymptotically $O(\varphi^n)$, this concludes that $gr(G_1)\geq \varphi$

**To conclude** that this is in fact an equality, the authors state that

> From this, it is not hard to see that an upper bound for the number of vertices at distance $n$ from $\Theta$ in the Cayley graph of $G_1$ is a constant time $\sum_{k\leq n}\varphi^k$, which, again, is just asymptotically a constant time $\varphi^n$. Hence $gr(G_1)=\varphi$

Is this because you can upper bound the number of vertices in $G_1$ (after $n$ steps) seeing that each one must belong to at least one of the Fibonacci trees starting at state $(-k, 0^\mathbb{Z})$, with $k=0,\ldots,n$ ? I'm think I have the right feeling, but I can't write the math properly. Any help is welcome.

Comment: is my answer below helpful?

Comment: Yes it was thanks, I was trying to see if I could get the authors bound more directly, but your answer is fine for me (I cannot yet award the bounty)

Comment: i feel like my answer is tight though...

Comment: it might, but I think we are over counting some sequences : for instance flipping on our way to the left, and flipping back the same switch when going to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma: The number of 0-1 strings of length $n$ avoiding $'00'$ is at most $C\varphi^n$.

Proof: Let $\Sigma_n$ be the set of such strings. Note $\Sigma_n = \{01c : c \in \Sigma_{n-2}\}\cup\{1c : c \in \Sigma_{n-1}\}$, so $|\Sigma_n| \le |\Sigma_{n-1}|+|\Sigma_{n-2}|$, yielding a fibonacci recurrence. $\square$

.

Main Problem: Let $f$ correspond to flip, $R$ to right, and $L$ to left. Note all elements of $G_1$ that can be achieved in at most $n$ steps can be written as a sequence of $f$'s, $L$'s, and $R$'s such that (1) there are no two $f$'s in a row, and (2) there is no $L$ appearing after an $R$ (i.e., we can WLOG that we go left for a bit and then only go right or flip from then on). For $0 \le k \le n$, we may consider the set of such sequences that don't go left after the $k^{th}$ step. Since the first $k$ steps comprise $f$'s and $L$'s without two $f$'s in a row, there are, by the Lemma, at most $C\varphi^k$ possibilities for the first $k$ steps, and then since the last $n-k$ steps are comprised of only $R$'s and $f$'s with no two $f$'s in a row, there are at most $C\varphi^{n-k}$ possibilities for the last $n-k$ steps. This gives me $\sum_{k=0}^n C^2\varphi^k\varphi^{n-k} = C^2n\varphi^n$. Although the authors say $C\varphi^n$, my upper bound $C^2n\varphi^n$ still gives $\varphi$ as an upper bound for the growth rate.